# About the representation of the Uninterpreted Function in Z3

Tags: z3

I have a quick question. I wrote a simple program (using Z3 NET API) and got the output as follows.

Program (Partial):

```
        Sort[] domain = new Sort[3];
        domain[0] = intT;  
        domain[1] = intT;          
        domain[2] = intT;  
        FPolicy = z3.MkFuncDecl("FPolicy", domain, boolT);      

        Term[] args = new Term[3];
        args[0] = z3.MkNumeral(0, intT);
        args[1] = z3.MkNumeral(1, intT);
        args[2] = z3.MkNumeral(30, intT);
        z3.AssertCnstr(z3.MkApp(FPolicy, args));

        args[1] = z3.MkNumeral(2, intT);
        args[2] = z3.MkNumeral(20, intT);
        z3.AssertCnstr(z3.MkApp(FPolicy, args));
```

Output:

```
FPolicy -> {
  0 1 30 -> true
  0 2 20 -> true     
  else -> true
}
```

I am wondering could I make the "else -> true" as false (i.e., "else -> false").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For quantifier free problems, Z3 (3.2) will select for the `else` the value that occurs more often in the `range`. By `range` here, I mean the finite set of values that Z3 assigned to a particular finite set of input values. In our example, only `true` occurs in the `range`. Thus, `true` is selected as the `else` value.

For quantifier free (and array free) problems, if the option `:model-compact true` is not used, then the value of the `else` doesn’t matter.
That is, if the formula `F` is satisfiable, Z3 will produce a model `M`. Then, if we change the value of any `else` in `M`, the resultant model `M’` is still a model for `F`.
Thus, you can ignore the `else`, or assume it is whatever you want, IF the input formula `F` is quantifier free, `F` does not use array theory, and `:model-compact true` is not used.
This property is based on the algorithms currently implemented in Z3, and this may change in the future.
In contrast,  the solution provided by mhs is not affected by changes in the implementation of Z3. In his encoding, any SMT solver (that succeeds in producing a model) will have to use `false` as the value of the function in every point not specified in the antecedent of the quantifier.

Another option is to use the `default` operator, and encode your problem using arrays.
When, the `default` operator is used, we should view arrays as pairs: (Actual Array,  Default value).
This Default Value is used to provide the `else` value during model construction.
Z3 also has several builtin axioms to propagate default values over: `store` and `map` operators.
Here is your problem encoded using this approach:

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(declare-const FPolicy (Array Int Int Int Bool))

(assert (select FPolicy 0 1 30))
(assert (select FPolicy 0 2 20))
(assert (not (default FPolicy)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Comment: That's the kind of better solution I was hoping for. However, are there any (possible) disadvantages of using the array theory?

Comment: The main disadvantage is the performance. Even if we use only `select` and `default`, there is an overhead. That is, if we do *not* use: `store`, `map` and `const` operators of the array theory. For example, all function applications will have an extra argument. The hashtable used to detect congruent terms is going to be bigger.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following ([RiSE4fun link](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/EaQh))?

```
(set-option :MBQI true)

(declare-fun FPolicy (Int Int Int) Bool)

(assert (forall ((x1 Int) (x2 Int) (x3 Int)) (!
  (implies
    (not
      (or
        (and (= x1 0) (= x2 1) (= x3 30))
        (and (= x1 0) (= x2 2) (= x3 20))))
      (= (FPolicy x1 x2 x3) false))
  :pattern (FPolicy x1 x2 x3))))

(assert (FPolicy 0 1 30))
(assert (FPolicy 0 2 20))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

The advantage I can see is that you can change it such that FPolicy(0 1 30) == false without touching the forall-constraint.
The obvious disadvantage is that you basically have to mention all argument tuples twice, and that the created model is rather convoluted.

I am looking forward to seeing better solutions :-)